# How can call on_menu_about(); function of UserMenu.js in Odoo 9?

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo-9

I want to create a odoo backend theme, so I use a icon for **About** tab, means when I click on the icon the About popup will be generated. I tried some code but that don't work:

.xml

```
<xpath expr="//ul[@class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right oe_user_menu_placeholder']" position="inside">
    <li><a href="#" onClick="web.UserMenu.on_menu_about();" data-menu="about" title="About"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a></li>
</xpath>
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

so just follow the code to get the answer .

.xml

```
 <xpath expr="//ul[@class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right oe_user_menu_placeholder']" position="inside">
     <li><a href="#" class="about" title="About"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a></li>
 </xpath>
```

then in .js file include this

```
var UserMenu = require('web.UserMenu');
var self=this;
var user_menu=new UserMenu(self);
$(document).ready(function () {
  $( ".about").click(function() {
        user_menu.on_menu_about();
  });
 });
```